# union in query is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, union

hi have an category table

```
categoryId
Categoryname
Type
```

these are column name's so i need to show all categories where type='card' but General category on top here is my code

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_Catagory` 
where CatagoryId=1 and type='Card' 
union select * from tbl_Catagory` 
where CatagoryId !=1 and type='Card' 
order by CatagoryId desc`
```

here i get `desc` order but `general` on bottom so what i need is `general` category on top with the remaining categories displayed in descending order based on `categoryId`

Comment: Can you also clarify: Is it `CategoryId` (as in the first part of the question) or `CatagoryId` (as in the code part)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `UNION`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Catagory
WHERE type='Card'
ORDER BY (CatagoryId=1) DESC 
       , CatagoryId DESC
```

This works because `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`. The first part of the `ORDER BY` makes sure that only those with `CatagoryId=1` are ordered first. Then, all the rest which are subsequently ordered by their CategoryId in descending order.

Comment: thanks for you response i tried your query i get CatagoryId CatagoryName  Type 
  280 March-1 Card  
    276 new                 Card                 
    277 Music                  Card                                  
                  1   General                    card

Comment: Do you have any rows with `CategoryId=1` ?

Comment: @ChithriAjay: And this query, as it is, does NOT show first the row with `CategoryId=1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `UNION` here, It can be done just with the simple `IF`

```
SELECT * FROM    
tbl_Catagory where Type='Card'  
ORDER BY IF (CatagoryId=1,CatagoryId ,1) DESC
```

Comment: thanks tt's working all most but when i add new category then i execute this query i get category id's  like this 1,280,282,277,270 so here  282 is new one so order like this 1,282,280,... like this

Comment: @Click: You can't put `DESC` inside quotes. It won't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fielda,fieldb,fieldc FROM 
((SELECT 0 as sortkey,fielda,fieldb,fieldc FROM tbl_Catagory where CatagoryId=1 and        type='Card' )
union  
(select 1 as sortkey,fielda,fieldb,fieldc from tbl_Catagory where CatagoryId !=1 and     type='Card' )) a
order by sortkey
```

The idea is to create the items you want on top with a literal value that you can sort by after the union has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed a back tick in second query's table tbl_Catagory.

Replace changes with this one:-

```
SELECT 
categoryId,
Categoryname,
Type  FROM `tbl_Catagory` 
where CatagoryId=1 and type='Card' 
union 
select 
categoryId,
Categoryname,
Type  from `tbl_Catagory` 
where CatagoryId !=1 and type='Card' 
order by CatagoryId desc`
```

Comment: i tried your query i get same result like id's like this order 282,280,1 but i need 1,282,280